# How to display order details in magento express checkout review page

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9, express-checkout

I use magento 1.9. I setup express checkout. But after hitting "Checkout with paypal" paypal review page doesn't display order details. Someone suggested to implement "GetExpressCheckoutDetails" api. But i don't know where i'll put it.

Anybody has solution?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RayuQ.jpg

Comment: Is there any option in the Express Checkout settings called "send line item details to PayPal" or anything like that?  Seems like I remember seeing that in Magento.

Comment: No There is no such option in magento admin.

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/magento-shopping-cart) there is.  The option is called "Transfer Cart Line Items" and is under the Advanced Settings for Express Checkout.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Actually i don't know how to send api request from magento paypal. I know what i have to put in code. But don't know where i'll place them? Magento or paypal.

Comment: You don't have to mess with code.  It's a single check box in the Magento Express Checkout settings.  I don't think you're reading the link I provided..??  Look at the 3rd bullet point under Step #9.

Comment: It's loading fine for me.  What do you mean "not working"?  Here's the full URL:  https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/magento-shopping-cart

Comment: I  meant link not found http://share.pho.to/9H0cH

Comment: I saw your link. I setup express checkout properly. Problem is when i click in "Checkout with Paypal" button it redirects me to review page. Problem is order description is blank. I don't know how to show order description in paypal review page.

Comment: Did you enable the line items?

Comment: I don't know about it. Please explain. I'm not familiar with review page setup.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you.  I've told you how to solve the problem and I've provided links to the step-by-step details on how to get that done.  You need to follow those steps.  You were saying you couldn't get the URL to load, so if that's still the case let em know and I'll copy the steps into the answer.

Comment: Those were implement exactly. But not working. See the screen shot where i stuck on. It is after hitting "Checkout with paypal" button http://i.stack.imgur.com/RayuQ.jpg

Comment: Show me a screenshot where you've adjusted the settings like that URL says to.

Comment: I put all paypal information in magento here is the screenshot. Problem is order details is not passing in paypal review page. But transaction is completing properly. http://share.pho.to/9J87c

Comment: You're not showing the "advanced" section of the settings, which is where the line items option is (as it shows in the doc I linked you to.)

Comment: Here it is http://share.pho.to/9JRbj

Comment: Ok, so there you can see the Line Items, and it's apparently set to Yes.  Has it always been that way or did you just set it that way?  Can you provide the API logs so we can review those?

Comment: Here it is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1umml2taTTolvg17iR0V2WneJCduO4QIdfXGIBacP5UA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So looking at the log I can see that the line item details are NOT getting included.  So if you do have that option correctly enabled and saved, but this is still happening, then my only guess could be you have some other extension that's conflicting with it.  Do you have any other 3rd party extensions installed?

Comment: I'm trying by disabling some extension.

Comment: Yes. For one third party extension this problem is appearing. That extension used to put a small additional price in checkout. Adding that additional price important. How i can recover this conflict?